# Expand div horizontally without overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="title">
           <span>Title</span>
           <div class="button">
               <div class="flyout"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am using following css

```
.title {
    display: block;
}

.title span{
   display: inline-block;   
}
.button{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

This is a header for a list entry that has a button for a `.flyout` menu.
I would like the `.title`-div to contain the `<span>` and `<div>` on one line. currently it breaks in two lines. Because of the `.flyout` I can not use `overflow: hidden`.
Is there an other way to achieve this?

Comment: both solutions do not work. there must be some other css that prevents this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to this  `white-space: nowrap;`

```
.title span {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```css
*{margin:0;}
.title {
    display: block;
}

.title span{
   display: inline-block;   
}
.button{
   display: inline-block;
}


.title span{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="title">
           <span>Title dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fs</span>
           <div class="button">
               <div class="flyout">ddddd </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**if you can apply to both than in one single line than used to this **

```
.title{
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
```

```css
 *{margin:0;}
    .title {
        display: block;
    }

    .title span{
       display: inline-block;   
    }
    .button{
       display: inline-block;
    }


    .title{
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="title">
               <span>Title </span>
               <div class="button">
                   <div class="flyout">ddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fsddddd dsfsd fs</div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you can use `white-space:nowrap` so the text will not be wrapped to new line:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/smg5028p/)

```
.title span{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;   /* add this line */
}
```

Resources:

- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space
- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp